# How to animate *independently* several sections of progress bars in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar, jquery-waypoints

I have some Bootstrap code which works perfectly well to animate a section of progress bars when it is viewed by the user.

However it animates **all** the progress bars in the page instead of animating **only** the progress bars in that viewed section. As a result, when the user goes to another section of progress bars, these are already animated and he does not see any animation.

My question is then: how to modify the code below to animate *independently* the different sections as they are viewed?

## CSS

```css
#skills {
  padding: 60px 0;
}

#skills .progress {
  height: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#skills .progress .skill {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#skills .progress .skill .val {
  float: right;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

#skills .progress-bar {
  width: 1px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: .9s;
}
```

## JS

```js
// Skills section
$('#skills').waypoint(function() {
  $('.progress .progress-bar').each(function() {
    $(this).css("width", $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + '%');
  });
}, { offset: '80%'} );
```

## HTML

```html
<!-- The first section of progress bars somewhere in the page -->
<section id="skills">
  <div class="skills-content">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria- 
   valuemax="100"></div>
        <span class="skill">Skillset 1 - Skill 1 <i class="val"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria- 
   valuemax="100"></div>
        <span class="skill">Skillset 1 - Skill 2 <i class="val"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Another section of progress bars further down the page -->
<section id="skills">
  <div class="skills-content">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria- 
   valuemax="100"></div>
        <span class="skill">Skillset N - Skill 1 <i class="val"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria- 
   valuemax="100"></div>
        <span class="skill">Skillset N - Skill 2 <i class="val"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria- 
   valuemax="100"></div>
        <span class="skill">Skillset N - Skill 3 <i class="val"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: change id="skills" to class="skills" and update your js code accordingly

Answer (score 3):

i just noticed you don't close your section elements and other tags properly

```
<section class="skills">
    <div class="skills-content">
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria- valuemax="100">
            </div>
            <span class="skill">Skillset 1 - Skill 1 <i class="val"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria- valuemax="100">
            </div>
            <span class="skill">Skillset 1 - Skill 2 <i class="val"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Another section of progress bars further down the page -->
<section class="skills">
    <div class="skills-content">
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria- valuemax="100">
            </div>
            <span class="skill">Skillset N - Skill 1 <i class="val"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria- valuemax="100">
            </div>
            <span class="skill">Skillset N - Skill 2 <i class="val"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria- valuemax="100">
            </div>
            <span class="skill">Skillset N - Skill 3 <i class="val"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

when your waypoint function called you each all your progress elements instead of only child progress elements

```
$('#skills').waypoint(function() {
  $('.progress .progress-bar').each(function() { // <- you are getting all progress elements
    $(this).css("width", $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + '%');
  });
}, { offset: '80%'} );
```

change to

```
$('.skills').waypoint(function () {
   var el = this.element;
   var children = $(el).find(".progress-bar");
   $(children).each(function () { // <- make sure getting only children elements
        $(this).css("width", $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + '%');
   });
}, { offset: '80%' });
```

and make sure other skills section not viewing by user when page loaded(not in the viewport)

[image: render]

Comment: also #skills to .skills , the OP has multiple skills section

Comment: This does not work, there are no animations. I changed '#skills' to '.skills' as suggested by @karthick but still no animations.

Comment: @michael code edited and tested you can try if you want

Comment: Ok this is now working, it was worth indicating in the bounty that the solution had to work then :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use different classes in your HTML and then in your JS initiate the different classes one by one when needed

```html
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria- 
   valuemax="100"></div>
        <span class="skill">Skillset N - Skill 3 <i class="val"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```js
$('#skills').waypoint(function() {
  $('.progress-bar.progress-bar-1').each(function() {
    $(this).css("width", $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + '%');
  });
}, { offset: '80%'} );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I cannot modify the javascript file for each progress bar i want to add, this would be against separatability of html, css and js. The solution of @onur-gelmez would be fine in this aspect, although it does not work...